# List comprehension having wrong length

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have list seeds and leechs which return 19 on asking length using len()
And using these two lists is a list comprehension -

```
sldiff = [(int(seed)-int(leech)) for seed in seeds for leech in leechs]
```

Each element is supposed to be the difference between the seed and leech(which are strings so have to be typecasted)
But `len(sldiff)` returns 361!
 My questions are - Why is it happening and what should I do to get required sldiff list?

Comment: 19*19 = 361 is a good starting point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a double list comprehension - ie you're iterating through the whole of 'seeds' for each entry in 'leechs' (so 19*19, ie 361).

Seems like what you actually want to do is iterate through one list, each entry of which is a combination of the relevant entry from seeds and the one from leechs. That is what `zip` does:

```
[(int(seed) - int(leech)) for seed, leech in zip(seeds, leechs)]
```

Comment: What the OP was doing is called a Cartesian product.

Comment: Thank you. I will mark your answer correct in about 11 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
[(int(seed)-int(leech)) for seed in seeds for leech in leechs]
```

is similiar as:

```
    temp = []
    for seed in seeds:
        for leech in leechs:
            temp.append(int(seed)-int(leech))
```

Apparently it is 19 * 19.

I think you want

```
[int(x)-int(y) for x, y in zip(seeds, leechs)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the result of 19 * 19 = 361 because of the two for loops.

I'm not exactly sure what you want but probably something like:

```
sldiff = [int(seed[x]) - int(leech[x]) for x in xrange(len(seeds))]
```

Assuming that len(seeds) == len(leechs)